# Multiple ajax calls in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage, function-call, variable-initialization

I am using jquery for my project.

I have the following requirements:

I need to make a function call which invokes 5 other functions.
These 5 functions are  ajax calls which work independent of each other. The ajax calls get data from server and appends values to a global object.

I am facing difficulty in finding whether all the ajax calls are done or not. After all the calls are done , I have to set it to localStorage and then load another html file.

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Atleast change the title of question with proper Problem statement

Comment: Since it appears you may be new here, I'd really suggest you read [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number of ajax calls made are constant,You can use the following logic

```
COUNTER=5;
function reduceCounter(){
    COUNTER --;

    if(COUNTER == 0)
    {
    localStorage.Obj=JSON.stringify(Obj);         
    location.href="nextPage.html";

    }
```

In each of your ajax calls , call reduceCounter() at .always();

eg:

```
$.ajax({
        url: ..
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',       
     })
    .done(){...
       //set Obj
     },
    .fail(){...
     },.always(){

     reduceCounter();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

mmm... Is it something you can do with jQuery Load, it makes sure everything loaded before you call any function or anything:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 //Make sure all DOMs loaded! 
}):
```